# Where is Update Policy failure logged

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I had a table with an [update policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/updatepolicy) applied like so:

````
.create table Foo (
    data: dynamic
)

.create function ParseFoo () {
    Foo
    | project 
        a = tostring(data.a),
        b = tostring(data.b)
}

.create table Bar (
    a: string,
    b: string
)

.alter table Bar policy update
```
[{
    "IsEnabled": true,
    "Source": "Foo",
    "Query": "ParseFoo",
    "IsTransactional": false,
    "PropagateIngestionProperties": false
}]
```
````

Someone<sup>1</sup> changed the definition of `ParseFoo` to extract another column:

```
.alter function ParseFoo () {
    Foo
    | project 
        a = tostring(data.a),
        b = tostring(data.b),
        c = tostring(data.c)
}
```

The difference in schema prevented the update policy from applying and data ingestion was stopped. I was able to figure out the mismatch and correct it, but I would like to proactively monitor for this in future.

From a very cursory glance, I don't see any errors related to the failed ingestion to this table logged in any of the places I've thought to check so far

- [`.show journal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/journal)
- [`ADXCommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/reference/tables/adxcommand) table

---

<sup>1. (me)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the link the [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60671684/4709762): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/management/updatepolicy#failures

```
.show ingestion failures 
| where TableName == 'Bar'
| project-reorder Details
```

```
Failed to invoke update policy. Target Table = 'Bar', Query = 'let Foo = 
__table("Foo", 'All', 'AllButRowStore') 
| where extent_id() in (guid(29f13c11-e6cf-472a-a1cd-91af4cfb2c44));
ParseFoo': Query schema does not match table schema
```